# Simple ordered MySQL query running very slow on a large table

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with ~ 1.500.000 records:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_locale` (
  `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `language` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci)
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`language`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;
```

With `item_id`, `language` as primary keys and index on `name` with size 255.

With following query:

```
select item_id, name from item_locale order by name limit 50;
```

The select takes around 3 seconds event though only 50 rows were required.

What can I do to speed up such query?

EDIT: Some of you suggested adding an INDEX. I mentioned above, that the `name` column is indexed with size 255.

I runned `explain` on the command:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item_locale | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1558653 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
```

Strange thing is that it is seems not to use any index...

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see how MySQL is performing your query.

Comment: An easy solution would be to add a covering index on item_id and name. Adding an index on `name` alone might suffice, depending on how MySQL handles combining indexes *(read as: I don't know)*

Comment: I added the result of an explain command.

Comment: @Vojtěch - Did you try adding a *covering* index on `item_id` and `name`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not around, so I could not reply to your message. Yes, I tried with no effect. This also happens for query without the item_id: `select name from item_locale order by name limit 30;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, there was some kind of problem with indexes - I dropped them all and recreated them again. And it finally works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving 50 Records is heavier too. Limit them to 10 Since you are using Order by also..

Comment: Limit it to 0 and it will even be faster <g>. Seriously, retrieving 50 records should never be the problem.

Comment: There are many Query Optimization Technique Like Index etc Please try to use them they will be beneficial

Answer (score 1):

Try to use query hint:

```
select item_id, name 
 from item_locale USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (name) 
  order by name limit 50;
```

also try to use

```
select item_id, name 
 from item_locale FORCE INDEX (name) 
  order by name limit 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply an index on the name field which might speed it up a bit.